# Difference between ようにする and ようになる

Tags: grammar, jlpt

What I knew about the ようにする／なる is 'to make sure'

What are the difference in usage?
Please give me examples of each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> V(可能形）＋ようになる　=> new ability
>
> V(辞書形）＋ようになる　=> new habit

あと数日で赤ん坊は歩けるようになるだろう。- In a few days the baby will be able to walk.

パットは私と話さないようになった。 - 
Pat doesn't talk with me anymore.

[More examples](http://www.tanos.co.uk/jlpt/skills/grammar/sentences/?grammarid=360)

> V(辞書形）＋ようにする　=> try to

知らせるようにします - I will try to report.

[More examples](http://www.tanos.co.uk/jlpt/skills/grammar/sentences/?grammarid=445)

Answer (score 1):

> 野菜を食べるようにする
>   (I) make it a point to eat vegetables
>
> 野菜を食べれるようになる
>   (I'll) be able to eat vegetables

The main difference is the former expresses a will to do something in the present, while the latter expresses a future state (in what something ends up).